# Content from eval() not rendering in desired location

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a token system which makes use of `preg_match_all()` to identify the potencial tokens in the page's content. The tokens contain the url of the desired widget file to be called into the content at the location in the content where the token was placed. `{widgets/top-ads/consider-covenant.php}`

**Example of Content with tokens:**

```
$content = '<p>Ham flank dolore cillum pork loin deserunt consequat strip steak. {widgets/top-ads/consider-covenant.php} Duis magna porchetta ribeye sed chicken t-bone alcatra fugiat salami aliqua do meatball ball tip. Strip steak turducken aliqua biltong sunt, hamburger cupidatat drumstick meatball. Shoulder ut est, spare ribs minim officia labore capicola chuck.</p>{widgets/top-ads/consider-covenant.php}<p>Pork loin tail commodo ball tip t-bone. Turducken dolore pastrami, culpa in commodo mollit prosciutto. Brisket incididunt nisi short loin landjaeger beef ribs jerky tempor capicola bresaola irure labore consequat. Quis in laborum pastrami chuck. Aliquip ham hock drumstick, turkey eu kevin pig doner jowl pork loin dolore est aute pariatur. Frankfurter consequat aliquip meatloaf quis.</p>';
```

The following function identifies the token and then makes use of `eval()` combined with `file_get_contents()` to get and parse the desired content, then uses `str_replace()` to replace the token with the desired content:

```
function replaceTokens($content){
    # run content through short code/widget preg match
    preg_match_all("'{(.*?)}'si", $content, $match); 

    # minimize content
    $content = str_replace("\r\n",'',str_replace("\t",'',$content));

    # replace token with content
    foreach($match[1] as $val) {

        # rebuild token for str_replace()
        $token = '{'.$val.'}';

        # get content
        $this_content = eval('?>'.file_get_contents($val).'<?php;'); 

        # replace token
        $content = str_replace($token,$this_content,$content);
    }
    return $content;    
}
```

The problem is with the `eval('?>'.file_get_contents($val).'<?php;');`. Rather than replacing the token at the actual location of the token, it replaces the token with the desired content but places it above the content itself and not in the desired location where the token was placed as shown [here](https://www.s8w.org/sample.php). (Note: the example widgets are on a 2-second delay)

If I use `eval(file_get_contents($val));` The token is replaced with the desired parsed content in the desired location but it adds `'?>` to the content as well.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `eval` but:

```
foreach($match[1] as $val) {

    # rebuild token for str_replace()
    $token = '{'.$val.'}';

    # get content
    ob_start();
         eval('?>'.file_get_contents($val).'<?php;');
    $this_content = ob_get_clean();

    # replace token
    $content = str_replace($token,$this_content,$content);
}
```

Sounds like what happens when you echo something you should be returning.  Because the echo happens before the returning.  And your content does too.

> Rather than replacing the token at the actual location of the token, it replaces the token with the desired content but places it above the content itself and not in the desired location where the token was placed

The `OB_*` set of functions all deal with output buffering.  So instead of sending it directly to the output, this captures it and puts it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @ArtisticPhoenix it resolved the issue

Comment: Sure, it was - pretty easy :-) ~ didn't realize it was only 7 min lol  Took me like 7 seconds.  It's something I have dealt with many times. And I use OB for other things.